# SDK manager and AVD manager acting funny

Tags: android

I'm getting some weird things happening when I try to create an AVD or launch the SDK manager. I've been searching for about half an hour and I think I have it narrowed down. Both the SDK manager and AVD manager exist twice on my machine.

They both exist here:

`C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdks`

and here:

`C:\Users\EGHDK\android-sdks\tools\lib`

I don't know how or when it happened, but I do know that it worked perfectly before and now it's misbehaving.

Shouldn't they only exist once? And if so... how do I go about deleting them?

**EDIT:**
Now I typed sdk manager into Win 7 search and I see it three times. Two likes I mentioned above and another in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

Does that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will exist in both in android-sdk as well as inside lib.
So nothing in wrong as it exist twice. Your problem will be something different.